# Can we always find such a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a finite $s$-dimensional grid $J\subset\mathbb{Z}^{s}$ containing $0_{s}$.

Let $n_{i}\in\mathbb{Z}^{s}$, $i=1,\ldots,N$ be the vectors with ending points the points of the grid.

Can we always find a vector $u\in\mathbb{R}^{s}$ such that all dot products $n_{i}\cdot u$, $i=1,\ldots, N$ are distinct?

My intuition leads me to believe the answer is yes, since I tried to find counterexamples in $1$ and $2$ dimensions but failed. I haven't come up with a solid proof though.

A re-formulation of the problem would be proving that there exists a vector $u\in\mathbb{R}^{s}$ such that 
$$(n_{i}-n_{j})\cdot u\neq 0$$ for all $i\neq j$. Given that the grid contains $N$ vectors, the number of vectors $n_{i}-n_{j}$ for $i\neq j$ is $(N-1)!$.

Any pointing to the right direction would be welcome.

Comment: What informs your intuition?  Can you say a bit about why you intuitively feel that the answer is yes?  I'm not trying to interrogate.  For example, adding context like "I tried to find a counter-example, but every example  I tried seemed to  support the claim, so I'm inclined to think the statement is true." Even if you have only the start of a proof, or the outline of a proof, that will help potential answerers better understand how to help you best.  And it also shows that you really have spent time on the problem. It doesn't matter  if what you've tried is wrong.  We've all been there!

Comment: Thanks, more added.

Comment: You're welcome, and good job with the edit to include a bit more! +1

Comment: Can we assume that if $(a,b)$ belongs to the grid then also $(-b,a)$ and $(b,-a)$  belong  to the grid? If so then we have always two identical dot products equal to 0..

Comment: @Nikon I see. The searched vector doesn't belong to the grid. Interesting problem.

Comment: Note that each constraint $(n_i - n_j)\cdot u \neq 0$ forbids a hyperplane. Since $\mathbb{R}^s$ is not the union of finitely (or even countably) many hyperplanes, it follows that there is a $u\in \mathbb{R}^s$ such that all the dot products $n_i \cdot u$ are distinct. It remains to prove that $\mathbb{R}^s$ is not the union of finitely many hyperplanes. If you can use a bit of measure theory or topology, the proof is very short. If the proof must use only linear algebra and a little set theory, it's going to be longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let a finite (or even countable) number of pairwise different vectors ${\bf n}_i$ be given. For $i\ne j$ one has ${\bf n}_i\cdot{\bf u}={\bf n}_j\cdot{\bf u}$ iff ${\bf u}$ is lying in the hyperplane $\>H_{ij}\!:\>({\bf n}_i-{\bf n}_j)\cdot{\bf u}=0$. There are at most countable many forbidden hyperplanes $H_{ij}$, and these hyperplanes do not fill all of space. It follows that there are plenty of vectors ${\bf u}$ satisfying your desires.

Comment: Very elegant. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianBlatter ok. there are many hyperplanes, but how to generate them? Is there a general method  which goes beyond the particular method using primes pointed by me?

Comment: @Widawensen: We are *given* the vectors ${\bf n}_i$. That they belong to a grid plays no rôle.

Answer (score 1):

After rethinking the problem I'm returning with a new proposition.

One of the solutions could be if you select components of this vector from the set of values being square roots of primes $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7}, \dots$ etc $\dots$ let name this set $\mathbb{S}$.

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2376746/polynomial-with-square-roots-of-primes) and comments with links provided by Jyrki Lahtonen follows that there is no possibility that any vector with components from $\mathbb{S}$ and vector with components from $\mathbb{Z}$ can have their dot product equal $0$ unless components of integer vector are equal $0$.

Note also that you can use values from the sets which look like, for example   $(\sqrt{3}- \sqrt{2}), (\sqrt{13}- \sqrt{11}),\dots,(\sqrt{73}- \sqrt{71}),\dots,(\sqrt{313}- \sqrt{311}) \dots $ and other appropriate  combinations with rational coefficients.
Selecting appropriately them you can obtain a vector which is very close (but not equal) to any predefined form, for example to vector $(1,1,1,..,1)^T$.

Comment: I came up with a similar solution in $2$-dimensions but was yet to generalize. Thanks, this was most useful

Comment: @Nikon For me your question was some kind of discovery that we can have a grid (like your grid generated by integers) and through appropriate stretching it ( for example by multiplying values on axis by primes) we can obtain new grid and vectors taken from these two grids are never orthogonal to each other. The proposition makes even a greater impression for original "grids" ( which are much more dense than integer) made from rational values and stretched by a similar method. Thank you for the question.

Comment: That's a very nice observation. My original problem was creating a invertible Vandermonde matrix produced by the powers of dots products between an unknown vector $u$ and vectors with integer components. Your thought generalizes the problem. Well done!